# On proof of $ \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_a^b | \cos{kx}|\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{2(b-a)}{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$I need to prove that 
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_a^b | \cos{kx}|\,\d x = \frac{2(b-a)}{\pi}.$$
The answer goes as follows: 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_a^b | \cos{kx}|\,\d x &= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int_{ka}^{kb} | \cos{x}|\,\d x\\
&= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{k} \frac{k(b-a)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} | \cos{x}|\,\d x = \frac{2(b-a)}{\pi}.
\end{align*}

But I'm little confused at the second step. I understand that the first step is a change of variable and I assume that the second is the same, but I didn't see why the $x$ in the integrand remains unchanged. As far as I see, it should be multiplied by $\dfrac{k(b-a)}{\pi}$, as it is multiplied by $k$ at the first step.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply, $\left|\cos x\right|$ is a $\pi$-periodic continuous function, whose integral over a period equals $2$. The interval $[ka,kb]$ includes $\left\lfloor\frac{k}{\pi}\right\rfloor$ periods and an extra piece whose contribute (bounded between $0$ and $2$) does not really matter for the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some handwaving going on in the second equality. The function
$|\cos|$ has period $\pi$. For large $k$ the interval $[ka,kb]$ contains
about $k(b-a)/\pi$ disjoint periods $[c,c+\pi]$ leaving a bounded amount
left over. So the integral is $k(b-a)/\pi$ times the integral
over a period plus $O(1)$.